# Can we use one one controller for two states when changing states using ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to switch between routes using angular ui-router. I have two views that use exactly same functionality. My view 2 uses almost 90 % functionality from my view one eliminating some of the html code. In that case can I use same controller for two states like this?

```
    // Routes
    .config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
        .state('moduleone', {
            url: '/moduleone',
            controller: 'moduleoneCtrl',
            templateUrl: path + 'views/one.html',
        })
        .state('module two',{
            url: '/moduletwo',
            controller: 'moduleoneCtrl',
            templateUrl: path + 'views/two.html',
        });
    }]);
```

Comment: If your remaining 10% is wrapped in an element you could just switch it off with `ng-if`. The general rule is one controller for each view but of course this is a mere guideline.

Comment: @MuliYulzary Thanks Muli. I wii try that out !

Answer (score 1):

Rather I'd say create a single state which will be to slight tweak displaying template. You can have mapping stored somewhere to decide template name.

**CodE**

```
var ids = {"1": "one", "2": two}

.state('module',{
    url: '/module/:id',
    controller: 'moduleoneCtrl',
    templateUrl: function($stateParams){
       return path + 'views/'+ ids[$stateParams.id] +'.html';
    }
});
```

Comment: Parakar Yes i have json file where the mappings are. But how to get rid of the unwanted html code in the new view page ?

Comment: @hhhh4 for the unwanted html code in the new template, use `ng-show` or better, `ng-if` to "remove" them. that boils down to the job of your controller

Comment: @CozyAzure Thank you. Will try that !